# How to pass variables between view controller using presentViewController in iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, variables, ios7, uiviewcontroller, sdk

some days ago I wrote a method to load a view controller using presentViewController:

```
-(void)passaGC:(NSString *)user
{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"generaC"];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

But today I need to pass the variable user from this method to the loaded viewController.

How can I modify my method to do this?

I found other question on stack overflow but nothing is really similar to my request

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: There are actually plenty of questions and answers on SO about this.

Comment: I understand but can someone help me to modify my method? Thanks

Comment: You need to do more than modify the method. The answer I linked to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers) provides step by step instructions for "passing data forward".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

add a property to your destination viewController (in the .h):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *user;
```

and finally your method will look like

```
-(void)passaGC:(NSString *)user
{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"generaC"];

viewController.user = user;

[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Thanks but How to parse/ get the parameter value.

Answer (score 4):

## Swift Solution

Except **@IBOutlets**, you can simply assing data to destination view controller properties.

#### DestinationVC.swift

```
var name: String?
```

#### SourceVC.swift

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Helper", bundle: nil)
let destinationVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DestinationSID") as! DestinationVC
destinationVC.name = "Mustafa"
presentViewController(destinationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```